# Editar Choice error en Modelo Django

Tags: django, django-models

Tengo el siguiente modelo:

```
class Producto (models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    estado_rev = models.IntegerField(choices = CHOICES_ESTADO_REV, default = CHOICES_ESTADO_REV[1][0])
    f_publi = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    f_act = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    descrip = models.TextField(max_length = 255)
    medidas = models.TextField(max_length = 255, null = True, blank = True)
    color = models.IntegerField(choices = CHOICES_COLOR, default = CHOICES_COLOR[0][1])
    marca = models.ForeignKey(Marca)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria)
    perfil = models.ForeignKey(Perfil, related_name='productos', on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    p_venta = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

El campo color tiene este choice:

```
CHOICES_COLOR = (
    ('','Seleccionar'),
    (1,"Negro"),
    (2,"Rojo"),
    (3,"Naranja"),
    (4,"Amarillo"),
    (5,"Azul"),
    (6,"Rosa"),
    (7,"Beige"),
    (8,"Marron"),
    (9,"Gris"),
    (10,"Verde"),
    (11,"Morado"),
    (12,"Blanco"),
    (13,"Plateado"),
    (14,"Dorado"),
    (15,"Multicolor"),
)
```

Cuando hago la migración en se ejecuta de forma perfecta, pero he añadido el siguiente valor al choice: `(16,"Estampado")` y me hace hacer una nueva migración en la que me da un error en el campo color porque "Seleccionar" no es un valor válido.

¿Hay alguna forma de saltar este error o de corregirlo?

Comment: puedes poner el error que sale, es decir el TraceBack

Comment: Lo he podido corregir, al realizar el cambio en la base de datos atendía a una migración anterior en la que estaba mal definida. Gracias

Comment: Ok, que bueno, recuerda siempre borrar los .pyc que se crean, para evitar eso mismo, al igual que algunas migraciones, suerte